# How to save file structure to text file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, tree, filesystems, backup

I have a folder of media files that are about 1TB big. I want to save the file names and directory structure to a text file for backup and reference. I want to attach a batch or PowerShell script to my backup process so the file gets saved before the backup. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the built in tree.com utility:

tree c:\folder /F

There's also a PowerShell function, Show-Tree, in PSCX 2.0:

http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/pscx-2-0-show-tree/

Answer (score 8):

a pure dir solution

```
dir /b /s c:\folder >foldertree.txt
```

has the advantages over Shay and mjolinor solutions that

1. it does not require powershell, just a plain cmd command
2. the result list contains the fully specified filenames which is a better format for postprocessing of any kind.

Comment: So perfect and so simple... (+1)

Answer (score 6):

To just save the directory structure and file names:

```
get-childitem <dir> -recurse | select -expand fullname > dirtree.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Open powershell in the folder
then run this to show the files tree in your powershell:

```
tree /a /f
```

or save it as txt file:

```
tree /a /f > tree.txt
```