# Use PowerShell to generate a list of files and directories

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, get-childitem

I'm writing a PowerShell script to make several directories and copy a bunch of files together to "compile" some technical documentation.  I'd like to generate a manifest of the files and directories as part of the readme file, and I'd like PowerShell to do this, since I'm already working in PowerShell to do the "compiling".

I've done some searching already, and it seems that I need to use the cmdlet "Get-ChildItem", but it's giving me too much data, and I'm not clear on how to format and prune out what I don't want to get my desired results.

I would like an output similar to this:

```
Directory
     file
     file
     file
Directory
     file
     file
     file
     Subdirectory
          file
          file
          file
```

or maybe something like this:

```
+---FinGen
|   \---doc
+---testVBFilter
|   \---html
\---winzip
```

In other words, some kind of basic visual ASCII representation of the tree structure with the directory and file names and nothing else.  I have seen programs that do this, but I am not sure if PowerShell can do this.

Can PowerShell do this?  If so, would Get-ChildItem be the right cmdlet?

Comment: Like `tree` under CMD? You could get the info with Get-ChildItem and organise the output to the host depending on the items returned yes.

Comment: Oooooo, tree gives me the directory structure.  That would be great!  Is there a way to get the files in there too, or something similar to that?

Comment: Yes Tree /F will do it.

Comment: There is also Show-Tree from the [PSCX](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/09/hey-scripting-guy-tell-me-about-powershell-community-extensions.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save file structure to text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569896/how-to-save-file-structure-to-text-file)

Comment: Tree /f does exactly I want to do, thanks a lot!  How can I strip out the part at the front talking about the volume, serial number, and drive letter though?  As far as a duplicate, in theory we have very similar goals, but I don't know about a duplicate.  Also, that "Show-Tree" command doesn't work.  I've determined that I have PowerShell 2.0

Comment: Show-Tree is not a native cmdlet. Its part of the PowerShell Community Extenstions PSCX which I linked in my comment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In your particular case what you want is `Tree /f`. You have a comment asking how to *strip out the part at the front talking about the volume, serial number, and drive letter*. That is possible filtering the output before you send it to file.

```
$Path = "C:\temp"
Tree $Path /F | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Set-Content C:\temp\output.tkt
```

Tree's output in the above example is a `System.Array` which we can manipulate. `Select-Object -Skip 2` will remove the first 2 lines containing that data. Also, If Keith Hill was around he would also recommend the PowerShell Community Extensions(PSCX) that contain the cmdlet `Show-Tree`. Download from [here](http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases) if you are curious. Lots of powerful stuff there.

Comment: Tree doesn't seem to show hidden files/folders, and doesn't seem to have a /force or similar switch. Is there any way to show hidden files/folders?

Comment: Does not appear to be a way no. Can't even find anything authoritative that specifically states this is normal behaviour

Comment: The capitalized "Tree" doesn't work on Linux, it's just "tree"

Answer (score 8):

The following script will show the tree as a window, it can be added to any form present in the script

```
function tree {

   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

   # create Window
   $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
   $Form.Text = "Files"
   $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(390, 390)
   # create Treeview-Object
   $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   $TreeView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(48, 12)
   $TreeView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(290, 322)
   $Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)

   ###### Add Nodes to Treeview
   $rootnode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
   $rootnode.text = "Root"
   $rootnode.name = "Root"
   [void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($rootnode)

   #here i'm going to import the csv file into an array
   $array=@(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\personalWorkspace\node)
   Write-Host $array
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {                                                                                                             
        Write-Host $obj
        $subnode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $subnode.text = $obj
        [void]$rootnode.Nodes.Add($subnode)
     }

   # Show Form // this always needs to be at the bottom of the script!
   $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
   [void] $Form.ShowDialog()

   }
   tree
```

Comment: What's with the local path `D:\personalWorkspace\node` ?

Comment: It is a folder location whose files are display

Answer (score 7):

In `Windows`, navigate to the directory of interest

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ right click mouse -> `Open PowerShell window here`

```
Get-ChildItem | tree /f > tree.log
```

Answer (score 4):

The best and clear way for me is:

```
PS P:\> Start-Transcript -path C:\structure.txt -Append
PS P:\> tree c:\test /F
PS P:\> Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use command `Get-ChildItem  -Path <yourDir> | tree >> myfile.txt` this will output tree-like structure of a directory and write it to "myfile.txt"

Comment: That does the same thing as "tree", and only gives me the directory structure.  How can I add the files to that tree?

Comment: Tree will have output but it will be from the current directory not `<yourDir>`

Comment: @Matt I've checked in such way and thought it will work in other cases

Comment: I tried "Get-ChildItem | tree" and got the same results as "tree".  I have PowerShell 2.0