# How to pass or pipe the results of tree to Powershell?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, tree, get-childitem

How can an array of files, as found through `tree`, be populated?

```
posh> 
posh>  tree ./  | Get-Item

    Directory: /home/nicholas/powershell

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           2/21/2021  5:42 PM                regex
Get-Item: Cannot find path '/home/nicholas/powershell/regex/├── a.log' because it does not exist.
..
Get-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
Get-Item: Cannot find path '/home/nicholas/powershell/regex/0 directories, 16 files' because it does not exist.

posh>
```

This example has no sub-directories, but for more complex directories, with sub-directories, looking to capture, for each file, its full path and filename.

Specifically, to then [search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66308742/4531180) the files -- but the question is of a somewhat general nature.

see also:

[Use PowerShell to generate a list of files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27447014/4531180)

https://superuser.com/q/1270040/977796

Comment: I'm a lil confused on what you're asking for? Can you rephrase what youre trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

`tree` is a CLI program found on windows and most Unix-style OSes for drawing a visual representation of a file structure. It does not generate an array of directories.

In powershell if you want to get the items of a directory structure recursively and save them to a variable (which would be an array except in the case where only a single item is returned) use the following:

```
$tree = Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

This will store the result in the variable `$tree`.
You can use the `-path` parameter if you want to start not at the current location. E.g.

```
$tree = Get-ChildItem -Path "/home/dave" -Recurse
```

Comment: Nice, but can you elaborate on what Unix-like platforms come with a `tree` utility? Neither macOS 11 nor Ubuntu 18.04 come with one, for instance. Since the default behavior of `tree.com` on Windows is just to print _directories_, the analogous `Get-ChildItem` call requires the `-Directory` switch.

Comment: To my recollection I had to install tree @mklement0 (for ubuntu)