# Visual Studio 2015 list all Views in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I want a list in of all the Views in an MVC project, in a text format (so that I can put it in a table and put in descriptions of the different views for documentation). Does such a list already exist somewhere in a project? Or a way of generating such a list without doing the obvious of writing code to grab file names do so?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with MVC, but wouldn't the solution explorer show you this?

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I wasn't clear enough. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I was about to post the same question, I don't suppose you ever found a solution for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Using dir and foldertree in cmd on the project views folder ended up working for me if you are in a windows environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569896/how-to-save-file-structure-to-text-file